# How to prevent google bots to crawl a specific part of a page?

Tags: seo, web-crawler, googlebot

I want google bots to prevent crawling of a specific part of a page say a div. My site is in angular and I am using escape fragment pages for seo.
I do not want to use iframe for that. Any suggestion?

Comment: Asking how search engines will display/rank/parse your site is off topic. It might be more suitable on [Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/), but check their scope and existing questions.

Answer (score 0):

The best way today is using `googleon`/`googleoff` tags to exlude certain parts of the site.

More on the topic to be found in [Google Search Appliance Help](https://support.google.com/gsa/answer/6329153?hl=en#57a1e30a-63b2-4470-86a5-94a6c06912be).

Comment: If you want to give a proper answer, please provide example (let's say a bit of code) or something that really helps the person asking.

Answer (score -1):

I can think of two ways through which this can be done:

**1- Using jQuery or Javascript**

Just wrap the part of the page that you don't want to be crawled in a div and assign it an id. Then, apply `display:none` style to the id in a css file and then make it `display:block` via either jQuery or Javascript on page load.

This bit of HTML, CSS and javascript should do it:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="hide-from-bots">The content of this div will be hidden from bots</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#hide-from-bots {
display:none;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function()
  {
      $("#hide-from-bots").show();
  }
</script>
```

**2- Detect User Agent and Skip the Content**

Another approach could be to somehow detect the USER AGENT and then wrapping the part of the page that you don't want to be crawled in a conditional statement like this:

```
if (USER AGENT != Googlebot){
  This content wouldn't render for Googlebot
}
```